Find the equation of the circle passing through $A(3,1)$, $B(-1,6)$ and s.t. the center belong to the line $3x-y=2$.
Find the equation of the circle passing through $A(3,1)$, $B(-1,6)$ and s.t. the center belong to the line $3x-y=2$.

The answer should be $(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=10$. However, it's not what I get, and I don't see where I am wrong.

The equation of the circle is of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$. Since $A(3,1)$ belong to the circle, we have that
$$(3-a)^2+(1-b)^2=R^2\tag{1}.$$ Since $B(-1,6)$ also belong to the circle,
$$(1+a)^2+(6-b)^2=R^2.\tag{2}$$
Since the center belong to the line of equation, we get $$3a-b=2.\tag{3}$$
Doing $(1)-(2)$ we get
$$(3-a)^2-(1+a)^2+(1-b)^2-(6-b)^2=0.$$
Factorizing the previous formula yield
$$(3-a-1-a)(3-a+1+a)+(1-b-6+b)(1-b+6-b)=0$$
$$b-a=3.$$
Combining with $(3)$ we get the system
$$\begin{cases}
b-a=3\\
3a-b=2
\end{cases}
$$
what gives $(a,b)=(5/2,11/2)$, which is not the wished solution. Any idea where I'm wrong ?

What you say is the answer does not go through B

@Paul, what do you mean ?

$(-1-2)^2+(6-4)^2=13$ not 10.

I’m voting to close this question because the atatement is wrong

Without much geometry and hardcore algebra method:-(let the coords of the centre be $h,k$)
$$3h-k=2...(i)$$
And by eqn of circles, $$
(3-h)^2+(1-k)^2=r^2=(-1-h)^2+(6-k)^2 \\
\implies 9-6h+1-2k=1+2h+36-12k \\
\implies -27=8h-10k ...(ii)  $$
Solving them simultaneously gives us $h=\frac{47}{22},k=\frac{97}{22}$.
Thus
$$r^2=(3-h)^2+(1-k)^2=\frac{5986}{484}$$
So equation:-
$$(22x-47)^2+(22y-97)^2=5986$$

A more geometric approach could be utilising the fact that the center also belongs to the axis of the chord AB, i.e. the perpendicular to AB passing through its center.
